# Error opening multiple modals

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the creatin of my web page. I want to use multiple pop-up modals but i can't seem to get it working. With this code when I only use one modal it works perfectly but when I try to add a second everything breaks and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would be really happy if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li> <div class="top_bar_menu" id="myBtn"> Our Story </div> </li>
        <li> <div class="top_bar_menu" id="myBtn-2"> Our Product </div> </li>
        <li> <a href="" class="top_bar_menu"> Our Team</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modalHeader"> Our Story </div> <br>
            <p>bla bla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal-2" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modalHeader"> Our Product </div> <br>
            <p>bla bla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-2');

    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn-2");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: you are using one variable for both modal and same in case of btn..the last will override

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to a problem, which is now solved. :D